# php concatenation is removing php output?

Tags: php, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a php variable that is created like so:

```
$scholarshipTitleOutput = ($scholarship['field_sec1_title']['#items'][0]['value']);
```

If I print the variable by itself it renders correctly, but I want the output to be placed between two header tags. What I would expect to be able to do it echo out the following...

```
echo "<h2>" . $scholarshipTitleOutput . "</h2>";
```

But this removes the variable output from the page for some reason. I've tested further and found that I can concatenate after echoing the variable to do things like add a space...

```
echo $scholarshipTitleOutput . " ";
```

So what is it about that first example that is completely removing the variable from outputting on the page?

Comment: HTML errors maybe? Look at the source code. What's there?

Comment: Is there something else going on? If you view the source of the outputted page, are the h2 tags there? Is the value of $scholarshipTitleOutput there?

Comment: Any error messages? Look at the HTML source, what do you see in both cases?

Comment: After checking the HTML source code, check your CSS. You might have something like `h2 { display: none; }` for all we know

Comment: There was nothing notable in the source code, and there isn't any styling that would be affecting the element... but I found a workaround so I'm not losing sleep trying to find out what was happening in the background. All of the answers are appreciated though!

Comment: What do you mean by *"nothing notable"*? Did you see `<h2>The value in your variable</h2>` in the HTML source or not?

Comment: I don't have the example anymore, but the h2 element wasn't appearing in the source code if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when I try it. You can also try

```
echo "<h2>{$scholarshipTitleOutput}</h2>";
```

Comment: *"It works for me"* type answers do not contribute anything useful